# Xampp 3.2.1 local copy of site 404ing on everypage apart from homepage

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, localhost, http-status-code-404

I have copied a site down from live (works fine) on to my local machine. Locally I can view my homepage of the site, however if I then try and visit another page I keep getting 404's.

here is my vhosts setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Sony\Documents\websites\website.com"
    ServerName local.website.com
    <Directory "C:\Users\Sony\Documents\websites\website.com">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone have an idea why this could be happening? Seems to only happen with the latest version of xampp and on urls that have been rewritten.

In case you are interested here is my htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# remove www from host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

# Don't match real existing files so CSS, scripts, images aren't rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Match the first two groups before / and send them to the query string
RewriteRule ^([+A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)?$ deals.php?country_code=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([+A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/([+A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)?$ deals.php?country_code=$1&zone_id=$2 [L]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: In your vhost config, add some logging for the rewrite engine: `RewriteLog C:\Users\Sony\Documents\rewrite.log` and `RewriteLogLevel 5`, then restart apache, try a few URLs and look at the log to see how things are being rewritten

Comment: thanks for the advise, I added the above to the foot of my vhost config and I cant get apache to start now.


10:07:37  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:07:37  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:07:37  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:07:37  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:07:37  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:07:37  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
10:07:37  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: It's possible that you don't have mod_rewrite loaded, and that you may need `AllowOverride All` in your vhost